# Typescript-Generic-Type that extends and has default

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on some react stuff and I was trying to do something like this:

```
class TextBase<P = {} extends TextBaseProps> extends React.PureComponent<P>
```

Now this gives me an error which is:

```
Parsing error: '?' expected. (eslint)
```

I fiddled around with it a bit and found that this doesn't give me an error:

```
<P extends TextBaseProps = {}>
```

But now when I'm trying to use that component it tells me:

```
Property 'onPress' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextNormal> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

Help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

almost forgot the interface:

```
interface TextBaseProps {
  children?: string | string[];
  onPress?: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
}
```

*tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck*

```
error TS2322: Type '{ children: string[]; onPress: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextNormal> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'onPress' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextNormal> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

38 <STD.TextNormal
```

**IMPORTANT**
I actually completely forgot an important piece of information. I'm extending that element again on which the property is now missing. The class definition:

```
class TextNormal extends TextBase {
    public constructor(props: unknown) {
        super(props, {
            color: Colors.fg.hex(),
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz that reproduces ?

Comment: @FRECIA It's actually in `react-native` but I'll see if the same error occures on stackblitz in plain react

Comment: Ok then could you place the whole error stack related to the first parsing error on your question ?

Comment: Thing is, the program works like a charm. Only VS Code and `tsc` complains. I'll provide the `tsc` output in the question.

Comment: Added some important information that I forgot to include

Comment: @FRECIA Ok I guess it's something that I didn't understand with typescript. This also happens in react in the stackblitz I just created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mwbcbk